# Qual melhor método para criar formulários no adroid?

Tags: android, android-layout, formulário

Estou criando um formulário de cadastro, para adicionar e editar registros em SQL.

Encontrei um lugar que indicava fazer através de `ScrollView`, para que o formulário tenha uma rolagem, e no meu caso seria mesmo preciso, pois os campos ultrapassam o tamanho da tela.

Mas o meu resultado está ficando muito feio:

[image: Print da tela de design de layout do Android Studio]

Achei muito interessante o esquemas mostrados na documentação do Material Design:

https://material.io/guidelines/components/text-fields.html

Mas é exibido apenas as medidas, não mostra exemplos em XML, e não faço ideia ainda de como fazer para ficar mais apresentável.

Alguém poderia me dar algumas dicas para melhores layouts de formulários, ou layouts no geral??

Alguém sabe se existe algum lugar com exemplos de layouts em XML gratuito para android studio??

Segue abaixo o código do layout que fiz até agora:

```xml
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorBackground"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
tools:context="br.com.teste.ActivityEmpresaCad">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EstEndereco"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/formendereco"
        android:inputType="textPostalAddress"></EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EstEndNum"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/formendnumero"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"></EditText>

    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EstEndCompl"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/formcomplemento"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EstEndBairro"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/formbairro"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EstEndLat"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/formlatitude"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EstEndLng"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/formlongitude"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    </EditText>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/ExibEndereco"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/exibEndlist"
        android:prompt="@string/formexibirendereo"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog"></Spinner>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EmprNome"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/formnomempresa"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/DescBasica"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/formdescricaobasica"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/DescSobre"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/formsobrempresa"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/DescProdServicos"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/fomrsobreprodservicos"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EmprRazaoSocial"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/formrazaosocial"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EmprCNPJ"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/formcnpj"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EmprWebsite"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/formwebsite"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EmprEmail"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/formemail"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"></EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/TelefonePri"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/formtelprincipal"
        android:inputType="phone"></EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/TelefoneOutrs"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/formoutrostels"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    </EditText>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/ExibTelefone"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:prompt="@string/formexibirtelefone"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:entries="@array/exibTellist">
    </Spinner>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/BtnSaveEmpresa"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/formbtnsalvar"
        android:onClick="saveEmpresa"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**---- ATUALIZADO ----**

Conforme sugestão do @regmoraes em utilizar `ConstraintLayout`, refiz o formulário e está ficando bem melhor. Resolvi mudar as cores tbm.

Segue abaixo o resultado do novo layout:

[image: Formulário com ConstraintLayout]

Mil vezes melhor e mais organizado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sinceramente, isso é uma questão de UX+UI. Você pode até utilizar os componentes do Material Design para seguir o guideline, mas como esses componentes serão organizados e o estilo deles, é você quem decide.

Em relação as dicas de criação do formulário, sugiro dividir ele em seções na scrollview ou telas diferentes. Dessa maneira o preenchimento fica dividido em etapas categorizadas ( Dados Pessoais, Endereço, Contato etc.) e não fica tão maçante.

Quanto aos exemplos, você pode encontrar alguns no [UpLabs](https://www.uplabs.com/material)

Comment: Obrigado por responder, sobre a organização e estilo do formulário eu ja tenho idéia de como quero, só não sei como realizar no android studio em xml. Criar uma idéia no photoshop pra mim é super fácil, agora fazer essa ideia virar código é que tenho dificuldade entende?

Olhei o site da UpLabs q vc me passou, e lá só tem ideias para o photoshop e arquivos em PSD, não tem nada em XML, pelo menos não encontrei. 

Sobre dividir as seções, seria com LinearLayout, como estou fazendo dentro do ScrollView??

Comment: Nesse caso, sugiro você utilizar o [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html). Dessa forma, você teria um scrollview com um constraint layout dentro, e dentro desse constraint, todas as outras views. Lembrando que usando esse layout, a principio, n é necessário utilizar relative layouts nem linear layouts

Comment: Cara o ConstraintLayout é muitooo bom, creio que deve ser mesmo a melhor maneira para os layouts de formulários. Dei uma olhada no link que você passou, ja estou reestruturando meu formulário, e está ficando muito mais organizado e elegante.

Obrigado mesmo por essa dica.

Comment: Editei a pergunta colocando o resultado do novo formulário com ConstraintLayout. Obrigado!!